# Is this a Loranthus Europaeus?

Tags: species-identification, botany

Location: Austria, Vienna Ottakringer Wald 
Date: Feb 8

I found something beneath a tree with epiphyta , which I thought to be *Viscum album* but is vividly yellow instead of white and I found no leaves.

[image]
[image]
[image]

My search of subspecies of *Viscum album* initially revealed:

> *Viscum album subsp. austriacum* (Wiesb.) Vollmann. Fruit yellow; leaves 2–4 centimetres (0.79–1.57 in). Central Europe. On *Larix*, *Pinus*, *Picea*.

But then I began to think it shouldn’t be *V. album*. In illustrations of *V. album* there aren't the thin stalks between berries and branches as in my specimen.

[image]

Perhaps [*Loranthus europaeus*?](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eichenmistel)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite right: it's [*Loranthus europaeus*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eichenmistel). Vienna was the prime example in our botany lectures where to see that plant without a fuzz.

c/p from the [Flora of Vienna](https://www.wien.gv.at/umweltschutz/naturschutz/biotop/florawien-kartierung.html):
"Auf Eichen, vorzüglich auf Quercus pedunculata und Qu. sessiliflora, selten. Im Eichenwalde von Schönbrunn, auf dem Gallizin, hinter Neuwaldeck, hin und wieder; viel häufiger auf dem Bisamberge {A}. ... auf den grössern Donau-Inseln z. B. ... in der Lobau {C}."

"Häufigkeit des Vorkommens: häufig bis sehr häufig"

(Confused about the contradicting "rare" and "frequent to very frequent" statements, but anyway.)

Here are some more [pictures](http://flora.nhm-wien.ac.at/Seiten-Arten/Loranthus-europaeus.htm).

Comment: The first „selten“ only applies to the case of quercus. He/she lists „locations“ in order of ascending probability.

Comment: I suspect your are right, but I can't be sure. Would have assumed to be the probability/frequency to be in brackets after _Q. sessiliflora_ if it would relate to frequency on the host.